# htmx: How to swap table row with hx-swap-oob?

Tags: htmx

I want to use [hx-swap-oob](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/) to replace a table row of the existing page "out of band".

in browser:

```
<table>
 <tr id="offer_1">....</tr>
 <tr id="offer_2">....</tr> (old)
 <tr id="offer_3">....</tr>
</table>
```

From Server to client:

```
<table hx-swap-oob="outerHTML:#offer_2" hx-select="#offer_2">
 <tr id="offer_2"> .... </tr> (new)
</table>
```

But up to now this is the result:

```
<table>
 <tr id="offer_1">....</tr>
 <table hx-swap-oob="outerHTML:#offer_2" hx-select="#offer_2">
  <tr id="offer_2"> .... </tr> (new)
 </table>
 <tr id="offer_3">....</tr>
</table>
```

I guess `hx-select` does not get evaluated when htmx get this snippet from the server.

How can I swap a row out-of-band?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the new extension **multi-swap**.
https://htmx.org/extensions/multi-swap/
It allows swapping multiple elements marked with the id attribute.
For each element it is possible to choose which swap method should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This does work:

```
 <tr hx-swap-oob="true" id="offer_2"> .... </tr> (new)
```

But it has a drawback:

You need to modify the method which creates this row. Depending on your context, you might already have a method for this. Why modify this method, just because the result of this method should get used out-of-band?

If you use Django, this snippet could get used to add the `hx-swap-oob` attribute after the HTML got created:

```
def add_oob_attribute(html):
    """
    I would like to avoid this ugly hack
    https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/423
    """
    assert isinstance(html, SafeString)
    new, count = re.subn(r'(<\S+)', r'\1 hx-swap-oob="true"', html, count=1)
    if not count == 1:
        raise ValueError(f'Could not add hx-swap-oob: {html}')
    return mark_safe(new)
```

I created an issue to find a better solution in the future:

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/423